# How to extract value from Regular Expression Extractor for requests in loop and pass these as comma separated in the subsequent request?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing

I have two requests:

- The first one is in a loop controller with the count as 4. I have implemented a Regular Expression Extractor for this request.
- The second request is outside loop and this consumes the value extracted via the Regular Expression Extractor reference name.
- I have given the reference name comma separated but it just takes the same value extracted from the 4th loop of the first aforementioned request.
- How can I have all four different values extracted and passed as comma separated in the second request that resides outside loop?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) **after** the Regular Expression Extractor
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def myVar = vars.get('foo')
   if (myVar == null) {
      myVar = ''
   }
   myVar += vars.get('your_var_from_regex') + ','
   vars.put('foo', myVar)
   ```
3. Replace `your_var_from_regex` with the Reference Name of the JMeter Variable you defined in the Regular Expression Extractor
4. You will be able to refer concatenated, comma-separated value as `${foo}` where required.

Example test plan structure:

[image: JMeter Concatenate Variables]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Dmitri Many Thanks first of all!
I don't have much idea about groovy. The code you suggested gives value like: "159010153123,159010153134," whereas I want value like: "159010150780","159010150776"

So I want to put "" after each value and omit the comma at the last. Please suggest!